# Pizza maker with Bloch builder

Tags: java, fluent-interface

I tried to implement the builder pattern of GoF. After searching for almost every related posts/examples on the Internet, I'm still confused. But I found that there are two kinds of patterns, which are both called *builder*:

- [Bloch Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1953567/5290519) : A famous post, but a comment pointed out it's actually a fluent interface, still useful, though. Also notice that it's not the same as Method Chaining, see the [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17937755/5290519).
- [Builder Pattern @thejavageek.com](http://www.thejavageek.com/2016/08/25/builder-design-pattern/) : The author gives a very clear structure of Builder Pattern: Director, Builder, ConcreteBuilder, Product.

---

Finally I decide to make my own version of "Builder Pattern", which follows the first link above, with some modifications:

- The static method `Pizza.makePizza()` acts as the Director.
- For simplicity, I didn't make the `Factory` a factory method or abstract factory, but it can be without problem.
- Before you want to make a pizza, you have to override some methods, which you can put anything must be done before the pizza is created.

---

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Factory myFactory = new Factory();

        Pizza myPizza = Pizza.makePizza(new Pizza.Builder(myFactory) {
            @Override
            public void prepareDough() {
                myFactory.prepareDough();
            }

            @Override
            public void prepareToppings() {
                myFactory.prepareToppings();
            }
        }.withSize(20).withBacon().withPepperoni());

        System.out.println(myPizza);
    }
}
```

Pizza.java

```
public class Pizza {
    private final int size;
    private final boolean cheese;
    private final boolean pepperoni;
    private final boolean bacon;

    private Pizza(Builder builder) {
        size = builder.size;
        cheese = builder.cheese;
        pepperoni = builder.pepperoni;
        bacon = builder.bacon;
    }

    public static Pizza makePizza(Builder builder) throws InterruptedException {
        builder.prepareDough();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        builder.prepareToppings();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        return new Pizza(builder);
    }

    public static abstract class Builder {
        private int size;
        private boolean cheese = false;
        private boolean pepperoni = false;
        private boolean bacon = false;

        public Builder(Factory factory) {
        }

        public Builder withSize(int size) {
            this.size = size;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withCheese() {
            cheese = true;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withPepperoni() {
            pepperoni = true;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withBacon() {
            bacon = true;
            return this;
        }

        protected abstract void prepareDough();
        protected abstract void prepareToppings();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("pizza={size=%d, cheese=%s, pepperoni=%s, bacon=%s}",
            size,
            cheese,
            pepperoni,
            bacon);
    }
}
```

Factory.java

```
public class Factory {
    public Factory() {}

    public void prepareDough() {
        System.out.println("Preparing dough...");
    }

    public void prepareToppings() {
        System.out.println("Preparing toppings...");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Preparing dough...
Preparing toppings...
pizza={size=20, cheese=false, pepperoni=true, bacon=true}
```

Comment: Please don't change or add to the code in the question after receiving answers. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: That would be fine if you want to post your improved code as an answer, if you explain what you improved about it. I wouldn't make that the accepted answer though, that would indeed be rude :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `main()` code feels cumbersome, and the modelling seems unnatural to me.  I also find that `.withSize(20).withBacon().withPepperoni()` is hard to read, perhaps due to its placement after the definition of the anonymous subclass of `Pizza.Builder`.

> ```
> public class Main {
>     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
>         Factory myFactory = new Factory();
>
>         Pizza myPizza = Pizza.makePizza(new Pizza.Builder(myFactory) {
>             @Override
>             public void prepareDough() {
>                 myFactory.prepareDough();
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void prepareToppings() {
>                 myFactory.prepareToppings();
>             }
>         }.withSize(20).withBacon().withPepperoni());
>
>         System.out.println(myPizza);
>     }
> }
> ```

Assuming that you are interested in constructing an immutable `Pizza`, I would prefer to see:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Pizza myPizza = new PizzaBase(20).addTopping(Pizza.Topping.BACON)
                                         .addTopping(Pizza.Topping.PEPPERONI)
                                         .bake();
        System.out.println(myPizza);
    }
}
```

In particular:

- This interface mimics the process of making a pizza.
- The base is *mandatory*, and you must specify its size.  The toppings are *optional*.
- Offering an `.addTopping(…)` method that accepts a parameter is more flexible.  You might even be able to `.addTopping(CHEESE)` twice to get extra cheese.
- I'm not convinced that dependency injection for the `Factory` is worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

Referent implementation of the [Builder](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Builder/).
I do not see Director in your implementation:

```
public class Director {  
   private Builder builder;   
   public Director(Builder builder) {
     this.builder = builder;
   }  
   public void construct() {        
      builder.createProduct().buildPart1("part1").buildPart2("part2");
 }}
```